# Add attribute to form widget not work

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to add the selected attribute to my `<option>` tags

```
{% for product in form.products %}
   {# of course this should only done inside a if, 
      but for testing purpose, it's okay #}

   {{ form_widget(product, { 'attr': {'selected': 'selected'} }) }}

{% endfor %}
```

However this does not work. Even exactly the same copy&paste from the symfony2 docs here does not work: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand

I'm adding the form element inside a FormType à la:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder
        ->add('products', 'entity', array('attr' => array('class' => 'choseable input-xlarge'), 
              'property_path' => false, 'label' => 'form.products.title', 'class' => 'Test\Bundle\Entity\Product', 'choices' => $products, 'multiple' => true, 'empty_value' => 'form.products.placeholder'));
}
```

All variables (`$products`) are ok in the example above.

Is there a problem?

I'm using Symfony 2.1.9-dev.

Comment: I think, it's because product is a subfrom, and not a widget.

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the question with form creation code? I'm pretty sure that Symfony is able to make item selected **only if** it's present in your model. But since you field is marked with `property_path => false` I don't think you can override this behavior...

An idea:

- Fetch all the data used in your entity field type and pass it to form object (either via constructor or options array)
- Add field as you're currently doing it
- Invoke setData right afterwards to set field data (using data fetched in step #1)

Btw, I am not big fan of `setData` but situation like this just calls for it :)

Hope that this helps...

Comment: Check my edit. It doesnt matter.. I'll update the question afterwards with the form creatiom code. (Im mobile atm)

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you tried setting any other attribute apart from `selected`? That way we could determine if this issue is attribute specific or not...

Comment: Sorry you were right, It matters if property_path is false or true... (and the 'attr' does not matter. It may be class or selected or whatever)

Comment: Ahm, I tried your answer with passing an array with the "selected" entities. And did right after $builder->add(..) a $builder->setData(array('selected'=>$selectedProducts));

But I'm getting a warning that the data is not of the same type of the form. 

Actually the form has another data_class, and the $products are just a part of the form. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Yes, you are correct... that `data_class` on the form itself should remain the way it it. Have you tried, maybe, to initialize form builder with pre-set data?

Comment: What do you mean with initialize form builder with pre-set data?
What I also tried to do, is to set another field (input-type text) which is in the Entity. This works fine. But how to do without Entity-property?

Comment: I will try to write some "tests" later tonight and will post it here. Currently it's a bit puzzle for me what could be going wrong ;)

Comment: any news here mr jperovic?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code. I reformatted the code below for better clarity.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    $builder->add('products', 'entity', array(
        'attr' => array('class' => 'choseable input-xlarge'), 
        'property_path' => false,
        'label' => 'form.products.title',
        'class' => 'Test\Bundle\Entity\Product',
        'choices' => $products,
        'multiple' => true,
        'empty_value' => 'form.products.placeholder'
    ));
}
```

1. Don't use class inheritance for form types (except of course extending `AbstractType`). Use `getParent()` for extending other types instead.
2. You can't set attributes of `<option>` tags manually. You would have to render the tags by hand.
3. For marking choices as selected, you need to pass default data to the field. Usually `getProducts()` would be called here to get the defaults, but you disabled that by setting `property_path` to `false`. So you should set the defaults manually by using the `data` option. Note that the defaults need to be an array/a collection, since `multiple` is `true`.
4. You are manually passing `choices`, which is a bad practice. If you just remove this option, the entity field can itself query the choices from the DB and optimize the needed statements for better performance.
5. Format your code. Really. :P

Comment: can you explain me the 3rd point with the setData. If i try to do this: $builder->get('products')->setData($selectedProducts); I get the exception, that $selectedProducts is an array and not a collection type... How is it possible to set the data manually? thanks for the rest, but your answer didn't help me that much..